# In Spring how to concatenate result of a static method during injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

During bean injection, I would like to take a return value from static method of a class and concatenate with something else to form a file location. Is there a way to do this in spring ?

Here is the static class

```
public class MyEnv{

   public static String getRoot(){
        return "/u1/temp/"
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<bean id="MyBean" class = "com.app.test.FileLoader">
     <property name="fileLocation" value = "#{'MyEnv.getRoot()'+'testfile.txt'}">
</bean>
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
"#{T(com.mypackage.MyEnv).getRoot() + 'testfile.txt'}"
```